# Xdebug: how to break program when a certain output occurs?

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, breakpoints

When debugging a PHP program with Xdebug, is it possible to set a kind of "conditional breakpoint" not on a specific line, but rather when a certain output is echoed?

This output could be specified by a certain string like `id="someid"` or by a regexp like `id="header(1|2)"`.

I believe this would be extremely practical when debugging - I know something is wrong with some part of my output, and I want to break the program at the point where it is produced, so I can work up the Call Stack and see what went wrong.

I am using PhpStorm and I would be satisfied by an answer explaining how to do that in this particular IDE. But since I suspect it won't be possible, I ask the question in more generic terms: would Xdebug allow for this?

Comment: PhpStorm can put **conditional breakpoints** (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-properties ) -- breakpoint will be triggered only if certain condition is triggered at that line. That's the best I can suggest here .. as I personally not aware of any functionality (both IDE or Xdebug) for controlling already echoed stuff (I hope you are using output buffering so you may inspect it).

Comment: Thanks. Conditional breakpoints are attached to a specific line, which defeats the purpose of asking the IDE to help me find the spot. 
The codebase is not mine, and it's huge, and not always well written, so solutions based on programming best-practices won't work here...
Since PhpStorm has a window showing all output I guess it theoretically _could_ have some logic to inspect it and break execution...